# Shell script now excecuting local script on remote server

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

So, i have two scripts below i am trying to run; mainscript.sh to remote login and execute attached.sh but the problem is when its executed i do not get to use the option set on attached.sh, it simply echos the option list. I think i am doning something wrong with i/o redirection. I am new to this, so any help much appreciated.

mainscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please enter ther server name : "
read servername


        ssh $servername "bash -s" < attached.sh
```

attached.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
OPTIONS="redhat Uptime logfile quit"
select opt in $OPTIONS; do

function redhat {
        cat /etc/redhat-release
}

function Uptime {
        uptime
}

function logfile {
        cat /var/log/messages | less
}

function quit {
        exit
}
if [ "$opt" = "redhat" ]; then
        redhat
elif [ "$opt" = "Uptime" ]; then
        uptime
elif [ "$opt" = "logfile" ]; then
        logfile
elif [ "$opt" = "quit" ]; then
        quit
else
        clear
        echo "bad option"
fi


done
```

Comment: is `attached.sh` on the local or remote server?

Comment: Attached.sh is in local server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard input is redirected to come from the script file; the script will be reading itself (and getting EOF, because the shell will already have read the script by the time it's running).

A somewhat clumsy but robust workaround is to `scp` the script file to the remote host, then execute it.  You could also play around with a different file descriptor so as to keep standard input connected to the terminal, but it tends to get tricky.